# Compare on-disk rules and in-memory rules (find the difference) for nftables

Tags: linux, nftables

I want to check that rules was loaded (e.g. ruleset in files are the same as in the kernel). I want to do it without modifying kernel rules. I can't compare files and `nft list ruleset` due to ordering, comments, formatting and so on.

Is there a way to see difference? Or, may be, there is a way to make nft to 'normalize' rules to match the format kernel rules are shown?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the `-j` option, that outputs a json instead of the human readable output with `nft -j list ruleset`.

You then only have to compare two json outputs, a task that can be done easily using a tool like `jd`.

The only issue would be how to convert the ruleset from the file to json.

Comment: Yes, that part (of converting config to some convergent machine-readable format) is the main topic for the question.

If I can do this, I can do the same for nftables list ruleset.

unfortunately, it's still open question